# Understanding Django model inheritance quirks

Tags: django

I'm having trouble understanding why certain properties exist in some models so I'm hoping that someone can explain them here.

Here's a basic example:

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    one = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Bravo(Alpha):
    two = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Charlie(Alpha):
    three = models.PositiveIntegerField()


"bravo" in dir(Charlie())
True
```

How is it that an instance of `Charlie` has a `bravo` property?  Is there a reason for this?  Did I miss something?

More importantly, why does this prevent me from adding a `bravo` property to the `Charlie` class?

```
...
class Charlie(Alpha):
    three = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    bravo = models.TextField()


Charlie()
ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "Charlie.bravo" must be a "Bravo" instance.
```

Comment: I *really* must get round to finishing my blog post on why you should never use model inheritance.

Comment: When you do, post it here would you?  I'd like to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance relationship introduces links between the child model and each of its parents (via an automatically-created OneToOneField).

In your case that means that with defining Bravo, Alpha gets propery named "bravo".

See [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) and [Inheritance and reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, this is a consequence of the fact that the parent class has an implicit foreign key to all its descendants, which is in turn inherited by the children. That probably shouldn't happen in fact, but there may not be any way of preventing it.

One possibility might be to [explicitly set the parent link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#specifying-the-parent-link-field) on Bravo so that its `related_name` is something other than 'bravo', so that you can reuse that name in Charlie.

```
class Bravo(Alpha):
    two = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    alpha = models.OneToOneField(Alpha, parent_link=True, related_name='not_bravo')
```